# How include more of one JS file - defer loading of javascript

Tags: javascript, deferred-loading

How Include more of one JS file in this Script, this S

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function downloadJSAtOnload() {
   var element = document.createElement("script");
   element.src = "defer.js";
   document.body.appendChild(element);
   }
   if (window.addEventListener)
   window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
   else if (window.attachEvent)
   window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
   else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
   </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

The English in the title is a little vague, so I hope I understand you correctly.

Firstly, the link below is an excellent guide for this.

[Guide for deferred Javascript](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/defer-many-javascripts.html)

Basically, if you want more than one deferred javascript you actually just include them in your "defer.js" file.

```
//Google plus button / badge
(function() { var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true; po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js'; var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s); })();

//Google analytics code
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){ (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o), m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m) })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', 'example.com');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```